# Wine 1.6 in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: windows, wine

So I downloaded Wine from the Software Center and it works very well. Unfortunately, the software center does not offer the latest version. My question is; when will the version be bumped to 1.6?

Answer (score 0):

Google 'can' be your friend... ubuntu + wine 1.6 ppa

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/wine